# Select Case Nested in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, nested, case

I want to calculate shipping cost based on Dlivery Location(Local, Regional, National) and Shipping Weight.
Shipping Charges are bases on three different different category of Package Type (Standard, Oversize or bulk) and also weight based.

I have created case nested but its working only on First case local, not working on others(Regional and National). Please help me to correct this code and explain what is wrong

```
Dim WT 'WT is Package Weight Type (Standard, Oversize or Bulk)
Dim STD ' Standard
Dim OVS 'Oversize
Dim BLK 'Bulk Size
Dim LC ' Location
Dim LCL 'Local
Dim RGN ' Regional
Dim NTN ' National
Dim EF ' Effective Weight on which cost will be calculated
Dim SHL ' Shipping cost 

Private Sub Shipping_calc()

Select Case WT
        Case Is <= STD
            Select Case LC
                Case Is <= LCL
                    Select Case EF
                        Case Is <= 0.5: SHL = "38"
                        Case Is <= 1: SHL = "54"
                        Case Is <= 2: SHL = "64"
                        Case Is <= 3: SHL = "74"
                        Case Is <= 4: SHL = "84"
                        Case Is < 5: SHL = "94"
                    End Select
                Case Is <= RGN
                    Select Case EF
                        Case Is <= 0.5: SHL = "46"
                        Case Is <= 1: SHL = "67"
                        Case Is <= 2: SHL = "82"
                        Case Is <= 3: SHL = "97"
                        Case Is <= 4: SHL = "112"
                        Case Is < 5: SHL = "127"
                    End Select
                Case Is <= NTN
                    Select Case EF
                        Case Is <= 0.5: SHL = "66"
                        Case Is <= 1: SHL = "91"
                        Case Is <= 2: SHL = "111"
                        Case Is <= 3: SHL = "131"
                        Case Is <= 4: SHL = "151"
                        Case Is < 5: SHL = "171"
                    End Select
                End Select
        Case Is <= OVS
            Select Case LC
                Case Is <= LCL
                    Select Case EF
                        Case Is <= 5: SHL = "101"
                        Case Is >= 5: SHL = (EF - 5) * 10 + 101
                    End Select
                Case Is <= RGN
                    Select Case EF
                        Case Is <= 5: SHL = "116"
                        Case Is >= 5: SHL = (EF - 5) * 10 + 116
                    End Select
                Case Is <= NTN
                    Select Case EF
                        Case Is <= 5: SHL = "166"
                        Case Is >= 5: SHL = (EF - 5) * 10 + 166
                    End Select
                End Select
    Case Is <= BLK
        Select Case LC
            Case Is <= LCL
                Select Case EF
                        Case Is <= 12: SHL = "241"
                        Case Is >= 12: SHL = (EF - 12) * 3 + 241
                        End Select
            Case Is <= RGN
                Select Case EF
                        Case Is <= 12: SHL = "241"
                        Case Is >= 12: SHL = (EF - 12) * 4 + 321
                End Select
            Case Is <= NTN
                Select Case EF
                        Case Is < 0 > 100: SHL = "NA"
                End Select
       End Select
        
End Select

End Sub
```

Code was cleaer, but somehow it did not work so I tried to change it
Now pasting the complete user from code here

```
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long

X = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Y = 6 To X

If Sheet1.Cells(Y, 1).Value = TextBox12.Text Then
Rows(Y).Delete Shift:=xlUp

End If

Next Y


End Sub

Private Sub cmdProfit_Click()

Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long
Dim RF   'RF Refferal Fee%
Dim FF   'FF Fixed fee
Dim SF   'Ship Fee
Dim TS   ' Total Sale Amount
Dim LC
Dim EF
Dim VM
Dim AW
Dim WT
Dim PR ' Profit

'WT is Weight Type Standard Oversize or Bulk
'Loc is location Local regional or National
'AW is Actual Weight
'VM is Volumatric Weight
'EF is Effective Weight Volumatric aor actual whichever is greater

X = Sheet1.Range("BA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Y = 1 To X

If Sheet1.Cells(Y, 53).Value = ComboBox1.Text Then
RF = Sheet1.Cells(Y, 54).Value

End If
Next Y

TextBox17 = RF * 100 'multiples 100 Only to show %value good, no referecen text box for this calc


TS = Val(TextBox5.Text) + (Val(TextBox5.Text) * Val(ComboBox3.Text))
TextBox13 = TS

If TS > 0 And TS <= 250 Then
FF = 2
End If
If TS > 250 And TS <= 500 Then
FF = 5
End If
If TS > 500 And TS <= 1000 Then
FF = 25
End If
If TS > 1000 Then
FF = 50
End If

'Dim LCL
'Dim RGN
'Dim NTN


If Opt2.Value = True Then
   LC = "Local"
End If
   
If Opt3.Value = True Then
   LC = "Regional"
End If

If Opt4.Value = True Then
    LC = "National"
End If

'Weight calculation starts from here

VM = Val(TextBox6.Text) * Val(TextBox7.Text) * Val(TextBox8.Text) / 5000 'Weight in KG

AW = TextBox9.Value / 1000 'Weight in KG


If VM > AW Then
EF = VM
End If
If AW > VM Then
EF = AW
End If

'Dim STD     'Standard
'Dim OVS     'Oversize
'Dim BLK     'Bulk




If EF < 5 Then
    WT = "Standard"
End If
If EF >= 5 And EF <= 12 Then
    WT = "Oversize"
End If
If EF > 12 Then
    WT = "Bulk"
End If


'Shipping Charges calculation

Dim SH
Dim SHL
Dim SHR
Dim SHN

'SHL for shipping cost shl used in case so SH is nt required
'SHR for Regional
'SHN for National




Select Case WT
        Case Is <= "Standard"
                        
              Select Case EF
              
                Case Is <= 0.5 And LC = "Local": SHL = 38
                Case Is <= 1 And LC = "Local": SHL = 54
                Case Is <= 2 And LC = "Local": SHL = 64
                Case Is <= 3 And LC = "Local": SHL = 74
                Case Is <= 4 And LC = "Local": SHL = 84
                Case Is < 5 And LC = "Local": SHL = 94
                Case Is <= 0.5 And LC = "Regional": SHL = 46
                Case Is <= 1 And LC = "Regional": SHL = 67
                Case Is <= 2 And LC = "Regional": SHL = 82
                Case Is <= 3 And LC = "Regional": SHL = 97
                Case Is <= 4 And LC = "Regional": SHL = 112
                Case Is < 5 And LC = "Regional": SHL = 127
                Case Is <= 0.5 And LC = "National": SHL = 66
                Case Is <= 1 And LC = "National": SHL = 91
                Case Is <= 2 And LC = "National": SHL = 111
                Case Is <= 3 And LC = "National": SHL = 131
                Case Is <= 4 And LC = "National": SHL = 151
                Case Is < 5 And LC = "National": SHL = 171
            End Select
                               
                                                                         
                                                                             
                           
        Case Is <= "Oversize"
                  
                  Select Case EF
                    Case Is <= 5 And LC = "Local": SHL = 101
                    Case Is >= 5 And LC = "Local": SHL = (EF - 5) * 10 + 101
                    Case Is <= 5 And LC = "Regional": SHL = 116
                    Case Is >= 5 And LC = "Regional": SHL = (EF - 5) * 10 + 116
                    Case Is <= 5 And LC = "National": SHL = 166
                    Case Is >= 5 And LC = "National": SHL = (EF - 5) * 10 + 166
                End Select
                                                                       
                                                
                              
    Case Is <= "Bulk"
                
                            
             Select Case EF
                    Case Is <= 12 And LC = "Local": SHL = 241
                    Case Is >= 12 And LC = "Local": SHL = (EF - 12) * 3 + 241
                    Case Is <= 12 And LC = "Regional": SHL = 241
                    Case Is >= 12 And LC = "Regional": SHL = (EF - 12) * 4 + 321
                    Case Is <= 0 And LC = "National": SHL = "NA"
                    End Select
        
End Select

'Profit calc RFA Refferal fee amount
RFA = TS * RF

Dim SA 'Sale Amount with out tax
Dim CP 'Cost price without tax
Dim AC 'Total Amazon charge=Referreal fee amount + Fixed Fee +Shipping
Dim TC ' cost price + gst

SA = TextBox5.Value
CP = TextBox4.Value


OTEXP = Val(TextBox10.Text) + Val(TextBox11.Text)
INGST = TextBox4.Value * ComboBox2.Value
OUTGST = TextBox5.Value * ComboBox3.Value

TC = CP + INGST

AC = RFA + FF + SHL
TextBox14 = AC

PR = TS - AC - TC - OTEXP + INGST - OUTGST

TextBox15 = PR
TextBox16 = PR / CP * 100

If PR <= 0 Then
MsgBox ("Please make sure you have filled all the required box Correctly. Increase your sales price")
End If

MsgBox (SHL)
MsgBox (EF)




End Sub

Private Sub cmdProfit_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

For i = 4 To 9

If Userform1.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = "" Then
   Userform1.cmdProfit.Enabled = False
End If
Next i

For j = 1 To 3
If Userform1.Controls("ComboBox" & j).Value = "" Then
   Userform1.cmdProfit.Enabled = False
End If
Next j


End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Worksheet
Set Y = Sheet1
X = Y.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

With Y
.Cells(X, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
.Cells(X, 2).Value = ComboBox2.Text
.Cells(X, 3).Value = ComboBox3.Text
.Cells(X, 4).Value = TextBox4.Text
.Cells(X, 5).Value = TextBox5.Text
.Cells(X, 6).Value = ComboBox1.Text

If Opt2.Value = True Then
   .Cells(X, 7).Value = "Local"
End If
   
If Opt3.Value = True Then
   .Cells(X, 7).Value = "Regional"
End If
If Opt4.Value = True Then
    .Cells(X, 7).Value = "National"
End If

.Cells(X, 8).Value = TextBox6.Text
.Cells(X, 9).Value = TextBox7.Text
.Cells(X, 10).Value = TextBox8.Text
.Cells(X, 11).Value = TextBox9.Text
.Cells(X, 12).Value = TextBox10.Text
.Cells(X, 13).Value = TextBox11.Text

Unload Me
Userform1.Show




End With




End Sub

Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
Unload Me
Userform1.Show
End Sub



Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long

X = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Y = 6 To X

If Sheet1.Cells(Y, 1).Value = TextBox12.Text Then
TextBox1 = Sheet1.Cells(Y, 1).Value
ComboBox2 = Sheet1.Cells(Y, 2).Value
ComboBox3 = Sheet1.Cells(Y, 3).Value
TextBox4 = Sheet1.Cells(Y, 4).Value
TextBox5 = Sheet1.Cells(Y, 5).Value
ComboBox1 = Sheet1.Cells(Y, 6).Value

If Sheet1.Cells(Y, 7).Value = "Local" Then
Opt2.Value = True
End If
If Sheet1.Cells(Y, 7).Value = "Regional" Then
Opt3.Value = True
End If
If Sheet1.Cells(Y, 7).Value = "National" Then
Opt4.Value = True
End If

TextBox6 = Sheet1.Cells(Y, 8).Value
TextBox7 = Sheet1.Cells(Y, 9).Value
TextBox8 = Sheet1.Cells(Y, 10).Value
TextBox9 = Sheet1.Cells(Y, 11).Value
TextBox10 = Sheet1.Cells(Y, 12).Value
TextBox11 = Sheet1.Cells(Y, 13).Value
End If

Next Y

End Sub

Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long

X = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Y = 6 To X

If Sheet1.Cells(Y, 1).Value = TextBox12.Text Then
 Sheet1.Cells(Y, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
 Sheet1.Cells(Y, 2).Value = ComboBox2.Value
 Sheet1.Cells(Y, 3).Value = ComboBox3.Value
 Sheet1.Cells(Y, 4).Value = TextBox4.Value
 Sheet1.Cells(Y, 5).Value = TextBox5.Value
 Sheet1.Cells(Y, 6).Value = ComboBox1.Value

If Opt2.Value = True Then
   Sheet1.Cells(Y, 7).Value = "Local"
End If
   
If Opt3.Value = True Then
   Sheet1.Cells(Y, 7).Value = "Regional"
End If
If Opt4.Value = True Then
    Sheet1.Cells(Y, 7).Value = "National"
End If
Sheet1.Cells(Y, 8).Value = TextBox6.Value
Sheet1.Cells(Y, 9).Value = TextBox7.Value
Sheet1.Cells(Y, 10).Value = TextBox8.Value
Sheet1.Cells(Y, 11).Value = TextBox9.Value
Sheet1.Cells(Y, 12).Value = TextBox10.Value
Sheet1.Cells(Y, 13).Value = TextBox11.Value
End If

Next Y
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

End Sub



Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
MsgBox ("Please fill all the required box")
Userform1.cmdProfit.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label15_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label16_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox13_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox17_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheet1.Range("A:A")) + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you setting the values?

Comment: Getting this values from user from.

Comment: So try stepping through the code to check if the values are correclty set? This way you can also check the value of RGN and NTN and see if the desired condition is met? If you do not know how to step though the code, then Google `vba step through code`. I got this as the first hit. https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code

Comment: If EF < 5 Then
    WT = STD
End If
If EF >= 5 And EF <= 12 Then
    WT = OVS
End If
If EF > 12 Then
    WT = BLK
End If

Answer (score 0):

As all your variables are declared but undefined, they are all considered equal, so every `Case` statement is true.

VBA executes at most exactly one `Case` statement - the first one it finds to be true.

> If *testexpression* matches any **Case** *expressionlist* expression, the statements following that **Case** clause are executed up to the next **Case** clause, or, for the last clause, up to **End Select**. Control then passes to the statement following **End Select**. If *testexpression* matches an *expressionlist* expression in more than one **Case** clause, only the statements following the first match are executed.

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement

Comment: Geeting this variables values from Userfrom in from textbox and comobobox EF = Effecive weight, which is If VM > AW Then
EF = VM
End If
If AW > VM Then
EF = AW
End If